# forwarding from controller to JSP

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, struts

I want to know how to forward request from a `ModelAndView` object in controller to a JSP page through `ForwardAction`. I have something like this in Struts. Kindly tell me how to do this in Spring

**InformLoginAction.java**

```
public class InformLoginAction extends Action{
public ActionForward execute( ........,......HttpServletRequest  request,
                                 HttpServletResponse response)
{
.
.
.
.
return(mapping.findForward("LOCMain"));
}
```

**struts-config.xml**

```
    <global-forwards>
    <forward name="LOCMain" path="/LOCMainMenu.do" redirect="false" />

 <action-mappings>
    <action
      path="/LOCMainMenu"
      type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction"
      parameter="crp.loc.main"><!--This is present in tiles-def.xml-->
    </action>
```

tiles-def.xml

```
<definition name="crp.loc.main" extends="crp.main" >
<put name="body" value="/menu.jsp"  />
```

To summarize, InformLoginAction returns "LOCMain" which forward to "/menu.jsp". Kindly tell me how this forward can be handled in Spring. I tried something like this in trade-servlet.xml. Please correct me

```
    <bean 
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean> 

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/menu.jsp">LOCMain</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="LOCMain" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController">
    <property name="viewName" value="/LOCMain" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
       <property name="location">
           <value>/WEB-INF/spring-views.xml</value>
       </property>
       <property name="order" value="0" />
     </bean>
```

I keep getting 'The requested resource is not available' error.

Answer (score 0):

Spring will forward to the return value of a Controller Handler Method if the return value is of type `String`. Or the view name if you return a ModelAndView. I prefer to return Strings.

```
@Controller
public class FooController {

  @RequestMapping("/LOCMainMenu")
  String getMenu() {
    return "/WEB-INF/views/menu.jsp";
  }
}
```

If the request URL is `/LOCMainMenu`, Spring Dispatcher will find and run your `getMenu` handler method. It will then forward to its return value.